# Why does this HLSL pixel shader not compile?

Tags: hlsl, pixel-shader

I'm working on a ray tracing pixel shader and came across a weird error. I wrote the following code solely to generate the error, it's pointless but I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

```
float4 main(/*Any input*/) : SV_TARGET
{
    uint uints[2];
    float4 light[2];
    uints[0] = 0;
    uints[1] = 0;
    uint c = 1;
    [loop] while (c > 0) {
        if (uints[c] == 0)
            light[c - 1] = 0.0f;
        else
            light[c - 1] = 0.0f;
        c--;
        break;
    }
    return light[0];
}
```

When compiled with shader model 5_0 (with and without optimizations) I get the following error:

```
error MSB6006: "fxc.exe" exited with code -1073741819
```

Doing seemingly meaningless things to the code, like removing `c--;`, gets rid of the error. Can anyone figure out what this weird error comes from?

Comment: What version of FXC.EXE are you using? Trying compiling directly from the command-line to see better diagnostics. It would also help if your code snippet above was buildable but you didn't include your definition of ``PS_INPUT``.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn I'm using the fxc.exe from the latest Windows 10 SDK (10.0.19041.0) (x64). As far as I know, the input doesn't matter. I get the error without any input as well.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it compiles if I remove the `[loop]` tag.

```
    // Compiling pixel shader
    ComPtr<ID3DBlob> pixelBlob = nullptr;
    ComPtr<ID3DBlob> pixelErrorBlob = nullptr;
    result = D3DCompile(pixelShaderByteCode.c_str(),
                        pixelShaderByteCode.length(),
                        nullptr,
                        nullptr,
                        nullptr,
                        "main", "ps_5_0",
                        compileFlags, 0,
                        pixelBlob.GetAddressOf(),
                        pixelErrorBlob.GetAddressOf());
```

```
float4 main(PixelInput input) : SV_TARGET
{
    uint uints[2];
    float4 light[2];
    uints[0] = 0;
    uints[1] = 0;
    uint c = 1;
    while (c > 0) {
        if (uints[c] == 0)
        light[c - 1] = 0.0f;
        else
        light[c - 1] = 0.0f;
        c--;
        break;
    }
    return light[0];
}
```

Comment: Yep, it works by doing some small changes, but I'm not trying to fix the code, only understand what's wrong with it.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't find any documentation for "[loop]" tag, maybe it breaks the compiler. It produces a segmentation fault c0000005

Comment: Strange, according to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-for) the `[loop]` attribute lets you `Generate code that uses flow control to execute each iteration of the loop.` and generally compiles fine for me. It's just reading/writing from arrays indexed by a changing variable in an if/else statement that produces the error, which I find very strange, probably a bug in the compiler.

Comment: Maybe they are only available for compute shaders not pixel shaders. I'm not sure.